# RT5372 Wireless Adapter Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, adapter

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on VMware. Ubuntu detects my wifi adapter (Panda Model No. PAU05) but I cannot see any visible wifi networks. The wifi adapter works fine on windows 10 I do not know why it will not work on Ubuntu 20.04.